# Eliminating duplicated rows by dropping varying columns and aggregating remaining rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that has duplicated rows simply because two columns are different from each other.

```
df
[A]    [B]   [C]   [D]  [E]
123    X     Y     5    A
135    D     E     4    B
434    R     F     3    C
434    E     Z     5    C
```

In the above example, column `[A]` should have unique values and is my key to determining duplicated rows.  As shown, column `[A]` shows a repeat at 434 due to `[B]` and `[C]` containing different objects.  As a result, column `[D]` is being split from 8 to 3 and 5 for each row and `[E]` is being repeated. (Column [D] is an arbitrary split based on other factors that aren't important to this example)

My goal is to drop the two columns causing the duplication and then aggregating columns `[A]`, `[D]`, and `[E]`.  Is there a way I can use `.groupby()` and set rules for aggregating non-integer values (for column `[E]`?  Aggregate is probably not the best word as I'm simply just taking the repeated instance and brings it up a level.  I'm thinking for column `[E]` setting rules where it outputs the first instance since both are unchanging.

I started off with the following method in mind: `df.groupby('A').agg()`

The example's output should show:

```
df_agg
[A]  [D]  [E]
123  5    A
135  4    B
434  8    C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is as simple as a `groupby` + `agg` -

```
df.groupby('[A]', as_index=False).agg({'[D]' : sum, '[E]' : 'first'})

   [A]  [D] [E]
0  123    5   A
1  135    4   B
2  434    8   C
```

---

If `[A]` is the index, then change the `groupby` syntax a bit -

```
df.groupby(level=0).agg({'[D]' : sum, '[E]' : 'first'})

     [D] [E]
[A]         
123    5   A
135    4   B
434    8   C
```

Comment: @ScottBoston With a slightly different answer  :-D

Comment: You guys are fast.  I had no idea the 'first' agg function existed.  Thanks so much! Because @ScottBoston got it first I'll give him the answer once the system permits me to, but I appreciate both of your input! Super [cold]speed[y]!

Comment: @ParalysisByAnalysis `as_index=False` is slightly more efficient than `groupby` + `reset_index`. I'd recommend doing a timing comparison and accepting based on the answer's merit, not the speed of the answerer ;-)

Comment: @ParalysisByAnalysis if you have more than two column . you can check the mine as well :-)

Comment: @COLDSPEED, you have a great point there.  All in all great answers but your timing was quicker computationally.

Answer (score 2):

Use, `groupby` with `agg` and a dictionary defined how to aggregate the columns.

```
df.groupby('[A]').agg({'[D]':'sum','[E]':'first'}).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   [A]  [D] [E]
0  123    5   A
1  135    4   B
2  434    8   C
```

Answer (score 2):

With this :-), then just select what you need from the result

```
df.groupby('[A]',as_index=False).agg(lambda x : x.head(1) if x.dtype=='object' else x.sum())
Out[275]: 
   [A] [B] [C]  [D] [E]
0  123   X   Y    5   A
1  135   D   E    4   B
2  434   R   F    8   C
```